# Remove characters from a cell and divide remaining float by 2 in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe with multiple columns where some cells contain the characters "DL" and a float. The other cells contain floats only.

For example:

|  | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | DL10.4 | 5.6 |
| row2 | 4.7 | DL8.8 |

I want use python to remove the characters "DL" and divide the remaining floats by 2. The cells without characters should be unchanged and not divided by 2.

Expected result:

|  | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 5.2 | 5.6 |
| row2 | 4.7 | 4.4 |

Comment: Basically you want to write a function that does three things: 1. Checks if there are characters in your value, 2. If so, remove characters, 3. After 2, divide remaining value by 2. Try to work this out, or search SO for answers to these subquestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)[`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for values after `DL`, divide by `2` and replace non `DL` valeus by original DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('DL(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False))
df = df1.astype(float).div(2).fillna(df).astype(float)
print (df)
      Column1  Column2
row1      5.2      5.6
row2      4.7      4.4
```

Comment: This works for the posted example, thank you a lot! I just noticed that it only works if every column contains at least one value with a DL, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @user19230313 - try `df1 = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('DL(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use applymap() method on the original DF and store the result in a new DF:

```
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: float(x[2:])/2 if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

This checks if the value is a string then slices all characters except the first two before converting to a float and dividing by two.

And if you want to keep the values rounded to 1.d.p you can just use the modified version below:

```
 df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: round(float(x[2:])/2, 1) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```py
df.applymap(lambda x: float(x.replace('DL', ''))/2 if 'DL' in x else x)
'''
     Column1 Column2
row1     5.2     5.6
row2     4.7     4.4
'''
```

Answer (score -1):

I will assume you have a way of looping through each row in the dataset.
With that in mind, something like this should work for you:

```py
import re
for row in df.iterrows():
    for col_value in row:
        reg_match = re.match("^DL([0-9]+\.[0-9])", col_value)
        if reg_match:
            num = float(reg_match.group(1))
            col_value = num
```

I'm not sure whether or not Python will complain about modifying the `col_value` in this case. If it does, you probably want to save the new values into a new data frame instead.

Comment: I would avoid `iterrows()` at all times

Comment: I don't doubt you, but could you tell me/us why?

Comment: Mainly: Speed. Read this article, explaining different methods of looping over rows: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06